# If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is bounded and $c \in \Bbb R_+$. Show that for any partition $\{x_o,...,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ that $U(P,cf)= cU(P,f)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R_+$ is bounded and $c \in \Bbb R$. Show that for any partition $\{x_o,...,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ that $U(P,cf)= cU(P,f)$.

Edit: My notation $U(P,f)$ is an upper darboux sum on a closed interval for the function $f$ with partition $P$.

So what I understand is that I am to show that

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sup \{cf(x)| x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \} (x_i-x_{i-1}) $ is equal to

$c \cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sup \{f(x)| x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \} (x_i-x_{i-1})$

Edit: Originally the problem was stated with $c \in \Bbb R$ but this had problems, so that it only makes sense if $c \geq 0$

Comment: Just wondering... is this the Darbaox definition of the definite integral?

Comment: @KSplitX edited yes.

Comment: What cases does it not work?

Comment: @KSplitX edited for an example which I think is correct.

Comment: We have problems when $c<0$. For example, $c=-1$. 

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. 

 The upper sum for any partition is clearly $1$. However, the upper sum of $cf(x) = -f(x)$ for any partition is $0 \neq -1$. 

The problem should say that $c \geq 0$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 good point.

Comment: $U(P, cf) = -cL(P,f)$ if c < 0, since $\sup -A = -\inf A.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stronger claim can be proven if $f$ has a Riemann integral, yet the process for the proof is the same.

Suppose you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x/c)$ for some constant $c$, and $f$ has a Riemann integral.

Then prove:

$$\int_{ac}^{bc}g=c\int_a^bf$$

Construct two partitions $P_0, \ Q_0$ such that:

$$P_0=\left\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\right\} \ on \ [a,b]\ and \ Q_0=\left\{cx_0,cx_1,...,cx_n\right\} \ on \ [ac,bc]$$

If we define:

$$m_i=inf\left\{f(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\right\} \ and \ M_i=sup\left\{f(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\right\} \ for \ i=1,2,...,n$$

Then the lower sums evaluate as follows:

$$L(P_0,f)=\sum_{k-1}^nm_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \ and \ L(Q_0,g)=c\sum_{k-1}^nm_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=cL(P_0,f)$$

Likewise, the upper sums are as follows:

$$U(P_0,f)=\sum_{k-1}^NM_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \ and \ U(Q_0,g)=c\sum_{k-1}^nM_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=cU(P_0,f)$$

It follows directly from the definition of a Riemann integral, that the claim holds, that is:

$$\int_{ac}^{bc}g=c\int_a^bf$$

Comment: Does the problem require $c \geq 0$ ? Important thought for future edits.

Comment: Well first of all, hopefully I did answer your question, was a bit confused what you exactly wanted, but the above problem seems very similar. As for your question, in the usual sense, the Riemann integral is bounded to values $\geq0$, yet this can be extended to the negatives if need be. My above proof assumes $ c\geq0,$ yes.

Comment: Haha np, this was one of my homework assignments a while ago, thought I'd share my solution. As a note, you can also prove another version of this if you consider a partition  in which you add a constant c, instead of multiplying. Same type of proof! :)

Comment: How can you guarantee that the $cx_i$ are contained in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Woops my bad, let me edit it, the $Q_0$ partition should be on [ac,bc]. This is actually why we require g(x)=f(x/c), intuitively, I think of it as shifting back the value, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that if $c \geq 0$ then $c \cdot sup(A) = sup (cA)$ the conclusion follows.